# Does TRPO train for multiple steps on the same data?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning

I understand mainly how [Trust Region Policy Optimisation](https://www.arxiv.org/abs/1502.05477) (TRPO) works, in terms of the trust region constraining the gradient updates from straying too far from the 'old' policy. Does this mean that in TRPO we perform multiple updates to the policy using the same data sample (similar to [Proximal Policy Optimisation](https://www.arxiv.org/abs/1707.06347) (PPO))? It does not seem clear to me from the paper whether this is the case, whereas in the PPO paper it is explicitly stated.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to CV! Could you explain what TRPO and PPO stand for? Also, could you add a reference to the paper you are mentioning?

Comment: TRPO - Trust Region Policy Optimisation (https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05477)

Comment: PPO - Proximal Policy Optimisation (https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06347)

Comment: Okay, I edited your question to include these.